# ios. Display special characters "th" and "gmt" with date

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I want to display a date in the following format "DDth HH:MM:SS gmt", but "th" and "gmt" should be of smaller size. How could I achieve this? Are there special unicode characters? Is it possible to display this in one UILabel? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use same UILabel with different fonts at the same time. Use three different Labels.

Comment: You could also create a custom view and do your own drawing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on iOS6 or higher you should be able to use the UILabel's attributedText property to set different font/color/size attributes for display. See here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText